# How to check character encoding of CSV file by Go?

Tags: csv, go

everyone.

I want to know character encoding of CSV file(UTF-8 or Shift_JIS) by Go.

```
file, err := os.Open("test.csv")
if err != nil {
    return err
}

// WANT: I want to know character encoding of CSV file(UTF-8 or Shift_JIS) 

switch  {
case "Shift_JIS":
    // TODO: convert and read the File.
    // Maybe: reader := csv.NewReader(transform.NewReader(file, japanese.ShiftJIS.NewDecoder()))
case "UTF-8";
    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
}
```

Comment: You cannot know the character encoding of a file from the file content itself (unless it contains this information). This is **meta**-data. The best you can do is parse in several encoding and use the one with the least errors (or the first with no encoding errors).

Comment: @CrouchingKitten It does not matter whether you do not know the encoding at all or not which of a finit set: You still cannot magically known. (Especially as Shift JIS and UTF-8 both "extend" 7 bit ASCII.

Comment: Indeed there is no way to differentiate Shift JIS from UTF (without BOM) by examining the data alone. Character encoding detection has long been one of the hard problems in programming, and in practically every case where detection is attempted, a user-controllable override must be provided because the automatic detection tends to be highly unreliable. If your UTF data includes BOM you could detect that, but it's very unusual to use BOM. You'll likely need to know when the file is provided what its encoding is.

Comment: @Volker : Well there's at least a JS tool which can detect them: https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js

Comment: @CrouchingKitten I am not sure what you want to imply with your comment. Do you think the existence of this JS tool proves me wrong? Are you sure this tool works as advertised?

Comment: @Volker He uses 2 functions from here UTF-8 / Shift-JIS. If both returns false or both returns true, then raises an error that the encoding cannot be determined. Otherwise uses the result: https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js/blob/master/src/encoding-detect.js#L55